# output of GROUP BY in SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below code.

```
select S.BUNDLE_ID,
       S.COUNTRY, 
       SUM(CONVERT(float,LV.VALUE_0)) AS BUNDLE_SUM 
from   PM_SCOPE S
JOIN   PM_LOOKUP_VALUE LV
    ON LV.SCOPE_ID = S.SCOPE_ID
JOIN   PM_LOOKUP_DEFINITION LD
    ON LD.LOOKUP_DEFINITION_ID = LV.LOOKUP_DEFINITION_ID
WHERE  LD.LOOKUP_NAME = 'Competitor Bundle Details - new'
  AND  convert(nvarchar, LV.EFFECTIVE_END_TIME, 112) > convert(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 112) 
  AND  S.BUNDLE_ID NOT IN (
           select distinct BUNDLE_ID 
           FROM   PM_SCOPE S
           JOIN   PM_LOOKUP_VALUE LV
               ON LV.SCOPE_ID = S.SCOPE_ID
           JOIN   PM_LOOKUP_DEFINITION LD
               ON LD.LOOKUP_DEFINITION_ID = LV.LOOKUP_DEFINITION_ID 
              AND LD.LOOKUP_NAME = 'Competitor Bundle Details - new'
           where  convert(float, LV.VALUE_0) = 0
              AND convert(nvarchar, LV.EFFECTIVE_END_TIME, 112) 
                            > convert(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 112)
           )
GROUP BY S.BUNDLE_ID, S.COUNTRY
```

This query ignores all the `BUNDLE_ID` in the `PM_LOOKUP_VALUE` table where `VALUE_0 = 0`. The problem here is that even if for any one country the `VALUE_0` is 0, the query is going to ignore the calculation of the sum for all the other countries also.

Is there some way I can add a clause in my query to only ignore the calculation for that particular country in case `VALUE_0` is 0?

```
Country     BUNDLE_ID     VALUE_0
US          BUNDLE1       10
UK          BUNDLE1       20
Poland      BUNDLE1       0
US          BUNDLE2       35
UK          BUNDLE2       30
Poland      BUNDLE2       10
```

If we look at the example above, I would like my query to only ignore `BUNDLE1` for Poland since its `VALUE_0` is 0 and still show me results for US and UK `BUNDLE1`.

`BUNDLE_ID` contains some components that's the reason I need to do a `group by` and sum it.

One additional example:

Country BUNDLE_ID   Bundle_Component    VALUE_0 US  BUNDLE1 A 10 US BUNDLE1 B   15 UK   BUNDLE1 A   5 UK    BUNDLE1 B   20 Poland   BUNDLE1 A   10 Poland   BUNDLE1 B 0 Poland  BUNDLE1 C   30

Bundle_Component is also a column name thats present in PM_SCOPE table. So here I want the sum of BUNDLE1 for Poland should not happen because B has a price 0 however for US and UK the sum should be calculated.

Comment: Did any of the answers suit your needs? Could you accept one or leave a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to group by the `BUNDLE_ID` and `COUNTRY`? If yes the `HAVING` should help:

```
SELECT S.BUNDLE_ID, S.COUNTRY, SUM(CONVERT(float,LV.VALUE_0)) AS BUNDLE_SUM 
FROM PM_SCOPE S
    JOIN PM_LOOKUP_VALUE LV ON LV.SCOPE_ID = S.SCOPE_ID
    JOIN PM_LOOKUP_DEFINITION LD ON LD.LOOKUP_DEFINITION_ID = LV.LOOKUP_DEFINITION_ID
WHERE LD.LOOKUP_NAME = 'Competitor Bundle Details - new' 
(...)
GROUP BY S.BUNDLE_ID, S.COUNTRY
HAVING SUM(CONVERT(float,LV.VALUE_0)) > 0
```

Comment: I want to group by BUNDLE_ID and COUNTRY. But I want my query not to do the sum  if VALUE_0 is 0 (like for Poland in my example above)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your condition on `BUNDLE_ID` should be replaced with a different condition. That said, the whole use of a sub-query is not necessary here. You can just put the zero-test in the join condition:

```
select   S.BUNDLE_ID,
         S.COUNTRY, 
         SUM(CONVERT(float,LV.VALUE_0)) AS BUNDLE_SUM 
from     PM_SCOPE S
JOIN     PM_LOOKUP_VALUE LV
      ON LV.SCOPE_ID = S.SCOPE_ID
     AND COALESCE(convert(float, LV.VALUE_0), 0) <> 0
JOIN     PM_LOOKUP_DEFINITION LD
      ON LD.LOOKUP_DEFINITION_ID = LV.LOOKUP_DEFINITION_ID
WHERE    LD.LOOKUP_NAME = 'Competitor Bundle Details - new'
  AND    convert(nvarchar, LV.EFFECTIVE_END_TIME, 112) > convert(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 112) 
GROUP BY S.BUNDLE_ID, 
         S.COUNTRY
```

Note the removal of the sub-query condition from the `where` clause and the additional line:

```
     AND COALESCE(convert(float, LV.VALUE_0), 0) <> 0
```

A solution with `having` would also work, but only if your values are guaranteed to be non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
    select * from ( select S.BUNDLE_ID,
   S.COUNTRY, 
   SUM(CONVERT(float,LV.VALUE_0)) AS BUNDLE_SUM 
from   PM_SCOPE S
JOIN   PM_LOOKUP_VALUE LV
ON LV.SCOPE_ID = S.SCOPE_ID
JOIN   PM_LOOKUP_DEFINITION LD
ON LD.LOOKUP_DEFINITION_ID = LV.LOOKUP_DEFINITION_ID
WHERE  LD.LOOKUP_NAME = 'Competitor Bundle Details - new'
AND  convert(nvarchar, LV.EFFECTIVE_END_TIME, 112) > convert(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 112) 
AND  S.BUNDLE_ID NOT IN (
       select distinct BUNDLE_ID 
       FROM   PM_SCOPE S
       JOIN   PM_LOOKUP_VALUE LV
           ON LV.SCOPE_ID = S.SCOPE_ID
       JOIN   PM_LOOKUP_DEFINITION LD
           ON LD.LOOKUP_DEFINITION_ID = LV.LOOKUP_DEFINITION_ID 
          AND LD.LOOKUP_NAME = 'Competitor Bundle Details - new'
       where  convert(float, LV.VALUE_0) = 0
          AND convert(nvarchar, LV.EFFECTIVE_END_TIME, 112) 
                        > convert(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 112)
       )
GROUP BY S.BUNDLE_ID, S.COUNTRY) a where a.BUNDLE_SUM !=0
```

Comment: Hi, a clearer picture of the data below                                                              Country BUNDLE_ID Bundle_Component VALUE_0
US        BUNDLE1        A                          10
US        BUNDLE1       B                          15
UK         BUNDLE1    A                          5
UK         BUNDLE1     B                        20
Poland BUNDLE1     A                        10
Poland BUNDLE1    B                    0
Poland BUNDLE1   C                        30

Comment: Bundle_Component is also a column name thats present in PM_SCOPE table. So here I want the sum of BUNDLE1 for Poland should not happen because B has a price 0 however for US and UK the sum should be calculated.

Comment: this isnt returning anything

Comment: Does all countries have a entry in table  PM_LOOKUP_VALUE with a entry VALUE_0 = 0

Comment: Yes they'll all have 0. I need to do a sum of BUNDLE_ID for all countries where none of the component values are 0. So for example, if for Italy a value is 0 however for Poland its not, i expect it to do a sum for POland. But right now its just ignoring all the BUNDLE_ID even if only one country has a value 0. I need it to filter data by country and bundle_id. Hope its clearer now?

Comment: I have Added the line ' AND S.COUNTRY NOT IN (select S.Country from PM_SCOPE S inner join PM_LOOKUP_VALUE LV on LV.SCOPE_ID = S.SCOPE_ID where LV.VALUE_0 = 0) ' for the requirement that you mentioned in the above comment .  How can this query return nothing please recheck your Db tables

Comment: Edited my answer try it now

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY S.BUNDLE_ID, S.COUNTRY 
HAVING SUM(CONVERT(float,LV.VALUE_0)) <> 0